# How can I do to extract some information with SQL Server ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this column with Microsoft SQL Server :

```
Date
6/19/2019 3:10:12 PM
12/23/2016 5:02:15 AM
13/25/2015 2:15:35 PM
```

And I would like to get two new column like this :

```
Date            Hour 
06/19/2019    15:10:12  
12/23/2016    05:02:15
13/25/2015    14:15:35
```

For the first column I just split the original column and I add a 0 for the first line and for the second I add a 0 and transform 03 to 15 removing PM. Thank you very much for the help !

Comment: any comments on the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would just cast to the types you want:

```
select cast(datetimecol as date) as datecol,
       cast(datetimecol as time) as timecol
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try_parse` as another option if it is a `varchar` column.

```
select try_parse('6/19/2019 3:10:12 PM' as date using 'en-US')
select try_parse('6/19/2019 3:10:12 PM' as time using 'en-US')
```

Or for your query

```
select 
   try_parse('datetimecol' as date using 'en-US'),
   try_parse('datetimecol' as time using 'en-US')
```